# I'm running Xamarin in visual studio and the main.storyboard is really slow to load. How to speed this process up?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm new to **Xamarin** platform and had been working with it for just about 2 weeks. I got all the basic setups configured, I have already managed to simulate it on my iPhone (provisioned through my macbook).

My main issue is every time when I want to continue to work on it, the main.storyboard **takes forever to load**. At first it was bearable, but it's happening everyday *(we're talking, 15-30 minutes)* and since I'm going to be working on it for quite some time, is there a way to speed up this process?

Running on Visual Studio 2015
& I'm using Xamarin Visual Studio 4.1, Xamarin Studio 6.1.0 and Xamarin.iOS 10

My pc is Windows 7, Xeon 3.2GHz 16GB ram and Macbook Pro Mid 2012 i5 2.5GHz 4GB ram

Any help or tips would be much appreciated!

Comment: What type of connection do you have between your PC and the Mac?

Comment: @SushiHangover remote login via Xamarin Mac Agent (PC through ethernet cable while Macbook through wireless connection but both on the same network)

Comment: 1) Try using a hardwired connection to the Mac, the ssh connection is chatty and I *personally* would not (and do not) use wireless for it. 2) Check your Mac's memory via `Activity Monitor`, what does the memory pressure look like? Assuming your PC's memory pressure is low and you are not paging? But check anyway. 3) There are not other users on that same Mac are there?

Comment: @SushiHangover 1) I can't find the closest ethernet socket (as there's only one) around my workstation so I have to settle with wireless. 2) Done that. Managed to halved my memory usage on Mac. Even though it doesn't solve my problem, I'm happy with how swift it is now ^^ 3) Nope, just me. Anyway, I updated everything into the updated version and most of my problems are sorted either by closing the application completely or restart one device or the other, or both. But hey, the main.storyboard is a bit faster to load than before. And I'll take that for now.